# dhtmlxEditor with full control buttons

Tags: editor, dhtmlx

When I added a dhtmlxEditor type, it shows only basic editor control button such as bold, italic, underline and erase.
ex)

```
{ type:"editor" , name:"notice", label:"Notice", labelWidth:600, inputWidth:600, inputHeight:279, labelLeft:25, labelTop:50, inputLeft:25, inputTop:71 }
```

How can I use toolbar option with full control buttons provided?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add property

```
{ ... toolbar: true ... }
```